# Compiling large header files C++

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, makefile, g++

My code is organized as

```
//LARGEHEADER.H

class LARGE {

 ...
}

//SMALLER.H
#include "LARGEHEADER.H"
class SMALL: protected LARGE {
...
}

//and in each of A.C, B.C, C.C ...
#include "SMALLER.H"
void f() {
 ...
}
```

Now LARGEHEADER.H is in the order of 10 MB. While trying to compile this setup it seems to take up a lot of time and memory and my final executable is close to 90 MB. Please point out to me what I am doing wrong. How can I speed up my compilation with this setup.

Comment: I would humbly suggest that a 10mb header is quite over size.  Regardless, can't you precompile your headers in gcc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Precompiled Headers in Header Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403211/precompiled-headers-in-header-files)

Comment: What's the point of seprating LARGE and SMALL headers if SMALL always includes LARGE?

Comment: @KevinDTimm Thanks for recommending Precompiled headers. I'll look into that

Comment: @SergeyA : I am working on some legacy code which is structured that way. So changing that would be the last resort (if it does help speed up compilation)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for suggesting the solutions of pre-compiled headers. Pre-compiling headers is an optimization strategy which does not address the root cause of the problem, which is coding style. Referring to this article

[Why does C++ compilation take so long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318398/why-does-c-compilation-take-so-long/318440#318440)

Including a large header file in multiple source/header files will cause the compilation to blow up (generate debug/symbol info for each includer). I re-organized the code to remove such dependencies.