# How to use/avoid #pragma inside #ifdef statement

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have code that is used across platforms (Windows and Linux). In windows the code uses precompiled headers so I include `stdafx.h` but in linux I don't. So I have this at the top of every .cpp file:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include "stdafx.h"
#endif // WIN32  // compiler error here
```

This compiles fine on linux but in Visual Studio 2013 I get the compiler error:

> Error 2   error C1020: unexpected #endif

I think it is because `stdafx.h` contains a `#pragma once` macro.

How can I fix this and is there a better way to make the code cross-platform?

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. `#ifdef WIN32
#pragma once
#endif` works fine in this [online VS compiler](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling stdafx.h in cross-platform code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191248/handling-stdafx-h-in-cross-platform-code)

Comment: The above duplicate suggests you have a typo in your code.

Comment: Surely the straightforward solution is not to use pre-compiled headers?

Answer (score 2):

This error you are getting because compiler completely ignores everything written before precompiled header. You can put desired thing in stdafx.h instead of conditional include of precompiled header.

Also please see this link https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/506745/visual-studio-2008-c-fatal-error-c1020-unexpected-endif